# RabbitMQ messages are in Unacked state

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

> Trying to listen to received message from RMQ, the messages are recived but messages in the queue are still in unacked state.

```
           ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();// assign factory details

           IConnection _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
           IModel  _model = _connection.CreateModel();
           _model.ExchangeDeclare("RmqExchangeName", "topic", true);
           var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_model);

            consumer.Received += (object ch, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) =>
            {
                   var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(ea.Body);

                    MemoryStream payloadstream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UriDto { Url = message })));
                    Helper.Log("Start  Message");
                    // Do something with payloadstream
                    Helper.Log("Sent  Message");
                    _model.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
             };
           _model.BasicConsume(RmqQueueName, false, consumer);
```

Comment: Start  Message and Sent Message are getting logged?.. _model.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false); This is the line responsible to acknowledge. However there can be some latency in acknowledging.

Comment: Just checked, messages are processing fine except the queue status being unacked.

Comment: You need to either acknowledge each message individually when finished or set auto ack to true (the false flag in your consume method)

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your exchange to a queue in order to consume your message.

```
       ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();// assign factory details
       IConnection _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
       IModel  _model = _connection.CreateModel();
       _model.ExchangeDeclare("RmqExchangeName", "topic", true);
       _model.QueueBind(queue: queueName,exchange: "RmqExchangeName",routingKey: "");
       var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_model);

        consumer.Received += (object ch, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) =>
        {
               var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(ea.Body);

                MemoryStream payloadstream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UriDto { Url = message })));
                Helper.Log("Start  Message");
                // Do something with payloadstream
                Helper.Log("Sent  Message");
                _model.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
         };
       _model.BasicConsume(RmqQueueName, true, consumer);
```

Comment: When BasicConsume:autoAck is set to true, the messages from the queue are not read.

Comment: @VivekRanjan are you sure that there is no error when retreiving data and you processing your message .

Comment: @VivekRanjan please can you try the new code ,  you need to provider the name of your queue when you bind it with your exchange